# How to use a older version of NLopt in R

Tags: r, nlopt

I am trying to replicate a code that uses the `nloptr` function. The only difference is that I am using another version:

As you can see here in my output I am using version 2.7.1

```
> # optimization result
> opt_result

Call:
nloptr(x0 = theta_init, eval_f = obj, eval_grad_f = grad, lb = lb,     ub = ub, opts = opts)


Minimization using NLopt version 2.7.1 

NLopt solver status: 4 ( NLOPT_XTOL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because xtol_rel or xtol_abs 
(above) was reached. )

Number of Iterations....: 15 
Termination conditions:  xtol_rel: 0.001    maxeval: 10000 
Number of inequality constraints:  0 
Number of equality constraints:    0 
Optimal value of objective function:  121997.975378908 
Optimal value of controls: 10.04425 52.50066 1 0.218371
```

However, in the original code they are using the 2.4.2 version of NLopt

[image]

Is there a way I can use the 2.4.2 version now? Because I want to have the exact same values (the code is the same, I just copied and pasted it).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Old versions of the NLopt sources are available at the NLopt GitHub page, under [releases](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/releases), starting with version 2.4.2.  You can install on the command line in the usual way:

```bash
$ curl -LO https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/archive/refs/tags/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz
$ cd nlopt-2.4.2
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Run `sudo make uninstall` in the same directory to uninstall, e.g., if you later decide to revert to the newest version.

Comment: This is for Linux right? I am using windows.

Comment: In principle, it should still work under the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Otherwise, you can try to adapt the NLopt installation instructions for Windows, [here](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_on_Windows/), but those still assume somewhat that you know what you're doing. You could also ask the maintainers of `nloptr` for advice.